# How to give a label like this?

Tags: equations

I am wondering how this was made. There are maybe `\centering` or `\enumerate` environments involved? And I can not figure out the (L) on the right. Here is the pic:

[image: equations numbered with lowercase Roman numerals with an uppercase L on the right-hand side of the page]

I would appreciate it if you could help me!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is just an `aligned` (with manual enumeration) within an `equation` and a custom `\tag`:

[image]

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{amsmath}

\begin{document}

\ldots the solutions
\begin{equation}
  \begin{aligned}
    & (i)  & \limsup_{t \to \infty} \, \lvert y(t) \rvert &< \infty, \\
    & (ii) & \liminf_{t \to \infty} \, \lvert y(t) \rvert &= 0 \Rightarrow
      \lim_{t \to \infty} y(t) = 0.
  \end{aligned}
  \tag{$L$}
\end{equation}

\end{document}
```

Comment: +1 but I believe you've missed a `\tag{$L$}`.

Comment: @campa: Indeed. Looked like a `(1)` originally.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply. I have just tried and it worked! thank you very much!!